# How to create multiple variables from function output in one line in js?

Tags: javascript, variables, coding-efficiency

I need to create 4 variables which will all carry a random composite number. The composite numbers are created by a function. Is there an easier way to create 4 variables using the same function instead of the below script?

```
var a = create_composite();
var b = create_composite();
var c = create_composite();
var d = create_composite();
```

Comment: Is there an easier way of creating four variables than creating four variables? Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit shorter, not sure if it's what you are going for though...

```js
// stub function
const create_composite = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)

const [a, b, c, d] = (new Array(4)).fill(0).map(create_composite)

console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

Another option would be to modify `create_composite` to accept the quantity of composite numbers you wish to generate:

```
const create_composites = (qty=1) => {
   return (new Array(qty)).fill(0).map(() => {
      // original composite number function code
   });
}
```

Then you could use this in a similar manner as I did above:

```
const [a, b, c, d] = create_composites(4);
```

While we are on suggestions for altering your `create_composite` function, the *best* option I can think of is to turn that function into a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators):

```js
function* create_composite() {
   while(true)
     // yield your return value here
     yield Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}
    
const [a, b, c, d, e, f, g] = create_composite();
console.log(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
```

This will allow you to take as many variables as you need

Comment: I might have to declare some composites in other scripts, so yes this would be beneficial. Thanks

Comment: Great! Glad to help out @Ansjovis86

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easies way. You can also do it that way:

```
var a = create_composite(),
b = create_composite(),
c = create_composite(),
d = create_composite();
```

This is depend on preferences but in JavaScript there is not easier way :)

Comment: Haha, yeah that would save me to write var three times. However, I'm hoping for something way shorter.

Comment: If in real you have more than 4 variables you can do it in any loop. If your function returns different values after each call there is no easier way to declarate 4 differen variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a browser that supports ES6, or are using babel or similar, you can do this:

```
var { a, b, c, d } = create_composite();
```

If create_composite returns an object with the keys a, b,c, d, then you'll have access to those individual variables.

Otherwise, in older browsers, you can still have the function return an object, you'll just have to call the properties individually as such:

```
var compositeNumber = create_composite();
console.log(compositeNumber.a);
```